# Accurev: How can I get a list of all users from a stream?

Tags: accurev

I need to get a list of all users who've contributed to a stream. I think I can just dump the entire history of the stream then parse it for the users like this (see [hist](http://www.accurev.com/download/docs/5.5.0_books/AccuRev_WebHelp/AccuRev_User_CLI/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=cli_ref_hist.html&single=true) for details):

```
accurev hist -s <stream> -a -fv
```

but this seems very crude, especially since I'm not interested in the history itself. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works nicely:

```
accurev hist -p <depot> -s <stream> -a -fv | sed -n 's/.*user: \(.*\)/\1/p' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the accurev hist command to obtain this information.

You can add the "-k promote"  option to restrict the output to show only promote operations.

Also, you can use the -fx option to format the output in XML and create script to generate a simple list of users.